# How to make my SanDisk Cruzer Blade 4GB disk back to normal?

Tags: filesystems, usb-flash-drive

Currently, my SanDisk Cruzer Blade 4GB have become a 64MB Firebird RAW flash drive (thumb drive). I don't know why it become like this but when I plug it into a PC, it suddenly transform itself to become a 64MB flash drive. (From 4 GB to 64 MB, that is a huge change!)

I read the following articles:

- http://forums.sandisk.com/t5/All-SanDisk-USB-Flash-Drives/Cruzer-Blade-will-not-format/td-p/214932
- http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1691847
- http://forum.hddguru.com/sandiskfirebird-64mb-t23539.html

and notice that their solutions do not work at all.

Some of their solution is as follows:

- Using the [HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool](http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=1970), which did not work for me as it could not format.
- Using the h2testw to see if it is genuine, which did not work for me because it is a RAW partition.
- Return to the vendor, which I doubt since the product only have 1 year warranty and it has expired.

I also notice that the flash drive is very fragile as after a few use, the flash drive have become something like the following: (The upper cover of the USB connector was broken or torn)

[image]

So, wondering if someone have any good solution to fix it back so that at least I can retrieve my data on the fragile thumb drive.

Comment: What operating system? Have you tried reformatting it by right-clicking on the drive and selecting format? (if you're using windows)

Comment: I tried on Win 98, Win XP, Win 7, Win 2008 and also tried reformatting it by right-clicking on the drive and selecting format but it just don't format.

Comment: Try running [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net), delete all partitions, create a new partition, format and if successful see whether [this utility](http://www.vconsole.com/client/?page=page&id=13) can test the drive. (Use data recovery utilities though if you want to recover existing data, and don't repartition/format in that case!)

Comment: @Karan, the problem is that I can't even delete any partitions, neither can I create or format it.

Comment: Does USB Flash Drive Tester have anything useful to say about the drive?

Comment: @Karan, it keep giving me this error `! Error in data at LBN = 0 (Off: 4h): expected 00000004h, encountered 00000000h.` from LBN 0 all the way to the last one. The strange part is that the software tell me this `Total errors: Read fatal=0, Read recoverable=0; Write fatal=0, Write recoverable=0; Comparsion=131071` -> meaning no fatal read or fatal write. But the problem is that the space have change from 4GB to just a small 64 MB!

Comment: I dont think putting a pencil in there is a good idea as it might damage it further

Answer (score 1):

Try running CHKDSK, open a command prompt and run

```
CHKDSK Pathname  e.g. CHKDSK E:\
```

This will look for errors and attempt to correct them.

Perhaps the volume is dirty: open a command prompt and run:

```
fsutil dirty query PathName
```

This will tell you the status of the disk, and it will run CHKDSK if it is dirty.

If nothing else, you will need to contact the place of purchase for a refund/replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Your USB has most likely become corrupt.

Open CMD and type in `diskpart`

when CMD shows in the output `DISKPART>` type in `list disk`

locate your 64MB USB drive. Mostly USB's are recongised as disk 2, **BUT PLEASE CHECK THIS OR YOU MAY LOSE IMPORTANT DATA!**

type in `sel disk (number)`

**WARNING: PLEASE MAKE SURE IT HAS SELECTED THE USB AND NOT A PARTITION ON YOUR HARD DRIVE!**

when it outputs `disk (number) is now the selected disk` type `clean`

Wait for the process to finish.

Close DISKPART and press WIN+R and type in `diskmgmt.msc`

Check to see if the full 4GB is there (In windows' case, 3.7GB*)

If it is, right click the partition and select "New Simple Volume"

Follow the steps and select "Quick Format"

You should now have your full 4GB Back.

*Windows technically does not use Gigabytes, but instead Gibibytes. Learn more here:

**EDIT: If it does not even let you run CLEAN, your USB drive has most likely triggered the read-only function in the firmware, which is irreversable**

[What is a Gibibyte?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte)

Comment: What is a Gibibyte?  Ans: - the inedible part of a chicken-